# HTTP Verb Tampering

Tags: php, web-services

We have detected our site is affected by "HTTP Verb Tampering" Vulnerability error. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: read this article : http://www.imperva.com/resources/glossary/http_verb_tampering.html

Comment: Umm, trace the specific problem and fix it?

Comment: No Haim, I didnt get useful message from that article.

Comment: Yes, I got the answer. Thanks stackoverflow.

Comment: Can you share the answer please? I am facing the same issue but I cannot find the answer!

Answer (score 0):

PHP with Apache server you can try this, if you are using rest services add additional methods needs like PUT etc. using limitExcept in your .htaccess file `<LimitExcept GET POST>Order Allow,Deny Deny from all <LimitExcept>`

Comment: Your comment is not very clear about giving an actual answer

Comment: Thanks Paul, notice i can not add new line in the comment, corrected :)